# Debug Assertion Failed! (string subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

OK. So I am making a simple program to experiment with strings, and during one portion of the program, a `for` loop displays each letter of the string in order, vertically. I ran the program normally to check on its progress throughout coding, however when I put this in, the error occurred. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
std::string word1 = "Chicken";
std::string word2("Nuggets");
std::string word3(3, '!');

std::string phrase = word1 + " " + word2 + word3;

std::cout << "The phrase is: " << phrase << "\n\n";

std::cout << "This phrase has " << phrase.size() << " letters!" << "\n\n";

std::cout << "The character at position zero is " << phrase[0] << "\n\n";

phrase[0] = 'S';

std::cout << "The phrase is now... " << phrase << "\n\n";

for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= phrase.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Position " << i << "'s character is " << phrase[i] << "\n";
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as is feedback on my code (as I am a rookie).

P.S. `<iostream>` and `<string>` were included, I'm just having trouble showing it to you on
the website. Sorry!

Comment: Try: `i < phrase.size()`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: Note that this would be valid for C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= phrase.size(); ++i)
```

You're going between 0 and `phrase.size()`, inclusive, which is too long. You should be going to `phrase.size() - 1`. Either change it to that, or change the `<=` to a `<` and you should be okay.

Example Fix 1:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); i++)
```

Example Fix 2:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= phrase.size() - 1; i++)
```

Edit - Longer/More Detailed Explanation:
Because if you have a String with 5 letters: "Hello", your actual indeces are:

- string[0] = 'H'
- string[1] = 'e'
- string[2] = 'l'
- string[3] = 'l'
- string[4] = 'o'

meaning that string[5] is going too far in this case. Since you're using 0-based indexing (as do most programming languages), you have to go from 0 to size-1

Comment: thank you Ricky! I tried fix 1 and that worked fine, but may I ask why? (I literally picked c++ up just a few weeks ago, so I am terrible at it.)

Comment: @MitarashiFox Because if you have a String with 5 letters: "Hello", your actual indeces are  string[0] = 'H', string[1] = 'e', string[2] = 'l', string[3] = 'l', string[4] = 'o', meaning that string[5] is going too far in this case. Since you're using 0-based indexing (as do most programming languages), you have to go from 0 to size-1. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this results in undefined behavior if you are compiling with C++03 as the index value cannot be greater or equal to the string size.

Using `operator[]` when `i == phrase.size()` with C++11 however is actually valid and will result in a null character (although this character can only be read and not modified).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Answer (score 0):

String indexes are counted as a zero-based index but it's length is still one-based.

If you have a string `s` with the characters "12345" `std::string::size()` will return 5, but s[5] is not a valid character because the valid indexes are `s[0]`, `s[1]`, `s[2]`, `s[3]`, `s[4]`.

Your for loop should be `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < phrase.size(); ++i)`.